# Ending verb when talking about BOTH

Tags: verbs, present-tense

In the sentence

```
Both options compile and run without problems.
```

what is the correct version of verb: compile or compiles (run or runs) ?
On one hand we're talking about two subjects, thus plural ending needs no -s. On other hand we're talking about each option specifically, thus "option runS".

Comment: The subject is *options*.  It's plural.

Comment: please write an answer and I will approve it

Comment: This question is a better fit for our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of the sentence (actually the head of the noun phrase that serves as the subject) is the plural *options*.  In some circumstances, a nominally *plural subject* will take a **singular verb**, but that happens when the many of that subject is considered as a unit. So we can say

> The *group* **is** meeting tomorrow.

Even though *group* means more than one person, the verb is singular because we think of the group acting as a single unit.  But here, as you note, the the word *both* emphasizes that we're considering two options that compile, each presumably on their own.

Two separate entities, so a plural verb.  You use the **singular** verb in

> Each option **compiles**.

because *each* means *each one*, or one at a time.